# How to take a back-date in calender according to time change [android]?

Tags: android, mysql, date

I'm developing an android app which involves ticket booking. Somehow I'm importing Google calendar and clock [using default version which is available in Android Studio v1.5].
My ticket booking condition involves subtracting the time and date while choosing the pickup date and time to avoid any future issue.
Now in this scenario I would like to change following things:

Reverse Time : When user selects a particular time [in 24 hrs clock] it gives that user new pickup time which is less than 7 hrs of picked time. i.e. If I select my time at 2 PM the pickup time it should show 9 AM on the same date. I somehow managed to apply the condition of each hour subtracting by 7 hours. But how can I do that because it's a headache to give condition to every hour of the day. If there any solution?

**Update: I found the solution but issue is, hen I choose AM time it's showing time in - [minus].**

Now the second issue is, if someone books my ticket on 1st of any month timed 2 AM in the morning, how can I change his date to previous date? As I'm subtracting 7hours from pickup date

For Example *[correct condition I'm expecting]* : If some user choose 2AM on 1st March then his/her pickup time and date should be on 28 Feb at 9PM.

Please suggest..! I'm attaching the code I'm using for this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    Button btnDatePicker, btnTimePicker;
    EditText txtDate, txtTime;
    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;
    TextView tvpick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnDatePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
        btnTimePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_time);
        txtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.in_date);
        txtTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.in_time);
        tvpick = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvpicktime);

        btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnTimePicker.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == btnDatePicker) {

            // Get Current Date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }


    if (v == btnTimePicker) {

        // Get Current Time
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        //    c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -6);
        //    Date picktime= c.getTime();
        //   tvpick.setText(String.valueOf(picktime));

        // Launch Time Picker Dialog
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {

                        txtTime.setText((hourOfDay) + ":" + minute);
                    //    tvpick.setText((hourOfDay+(-6)) + ":" + minute);

                        if(hourOfDay==00)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((17) + ":" + minute);

                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==1)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((18) + ":" + minute );
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==2)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((19) + ":" + minute );
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==3)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((20) + ":" + minute );
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==4)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((21) + ":" + minute);
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==5)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((22) + ":" + minute );
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==6)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((23) + ":" + minute);
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==7)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((00) + ":" + minute);
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==8)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((01) + ":" + minute);
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==9)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((02) + ":" + minute);
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==10)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((03) + ":" + minute);
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==11)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((04) + ":" + minute);
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==12)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((05) + ":" + minute);
                        }
                        if(hourOfDay==13)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((06) + ":" + minute);
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==14)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((07) + ":" + minute );
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==15)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((8) + ":" + minute );
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==16)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((9) + ":" + minute);
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==17)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((10) + ":" + minute );
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==18)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((11) + ":" + minute);
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==19)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((12) + ":" + minute);
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==20)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((13) + ":" + minute);
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==21)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((14) + ":" + minute);
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==22)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((15) + ":" + minute);
                        }
                        else if(hourOfDay==23)
                        {
                            tvpick.setText((16) + ":" + minute);
                        }
                    }
                }, mHour, mMinute, false);
        timePickerDialog.show();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to adjust for time zones by your subtracting seven hours? If so, you are doing this the very wrong and very difficult way. Or is the minus seven hours part of your business logic?

Answer (score 1):

To start off: Java calendar objects suck. That being said... You must use them for this situation.

To subtract time from any date simply do the following:

```
    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, -7);
    date.setTime(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

The output of this would be whatever date/time the 'date' object had minus 7 hours. This includes handling switching months & years. even for leap years!

To be clear this is simply how I would approach the issue. It really depends what date format you start off with vs. what you want to end up with.

Comment: how i show this above function result in text field?

Comment: Be a little more precise... Do you mean how do you format date objects to strings?

Comment: yes i want to show the result in textview. how to do?

Comment: Try the following: DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", dateObject);

Comment: the above code shows current date and time but i want the time which i pick manually from picker and date shiould reflect according to time picked. example. suppose i select 2am and date is 1-9-2016 from picker then i want to show result -7 hours back to selected time i.e. 19pm and the date is 30-8-2016.How do i?

Comment: Then simply create a new calendar object inside the time picker dialogue. Set the hour of day/minutes. Then subtract 7 hours.

Comment: TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                             int minute) {

                            txtTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);

Comment: Date date = new Date();
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calendar.setTime(date);
                            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, -7);
                            date.setTime(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
                            DateFormat.format("dd/mm/yyyy", date);
                            String d= (String) DateFormat.format("dd/mm/yyyy", date);
                            tvpick.setText(String.valueOf(date));


                        }
                    }, mHour, mMinute, false);